# Why adding a new NotificationServiceExtension target is causing a cycle error in build phase?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I wanted to add support for remote notification following this docs:
[Remote Notification support](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/remote-notification-support)

I added a new NotificationServiceExtension from Xcode by selecting my main target and then File > New >Target

But when I added this in my Podfile:

```
$NotifeeExtension = true  
target 'NotifeeNotificationService' do   
    pod 'RNNotifeeCore', :path => '../node_modules/@notifee/react-native/RNNotifeeCore.podspec' 
end
```

I reinstalled pods successfully although when I try to build the project I get a circular error:

```
Showing All Errors Only
Cycle inside MyTarget; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'MyTarget': CodeSign /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'MyTarget': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'MyTarget': script phase “[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration”
○ Target 'MyTarget' has process command with output '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'MyTarget' has copy command from '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotifeeNotificationService.appex' to '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/PlugIns/NotifeeNotificationService.appex'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target: ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/\_CodeSignature ->

command: P0:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework ->

command: P2:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyTarget.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.build/Script-D93507C60CD096060E86883C.sh ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyTarget.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.build/InputFileList-D93507C60CD096060E86883C-Pods-MyTarget-frameworks-Debug-input-files-f2830ef58d1eecd1e5f891214f592d0e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyTarget.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.build/InputFileList-D93507C60CD096060E86883C-Pods-MyTarget-frameworks-Debug-input-files-f2830ef58d1eecd1e5f891214f592d0e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: <target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase4--cp-user---rnfb--core-configuration> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase4--cp-user---rnfb--core-configuration ->

node: <execute-shell-script-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d82a5d6e7dc623fbd840bdb742151172b37-target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-> ->

command: P2:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyTarget.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.build/Script-9FBE5B3F37CD587C2140ED9F.sh ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/Info.plist /Users/myuser/Desktop/Projekte/MyTarget/ios/MyTarget/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/PlugIns/NotifeeNotificationService.appex ->

command: P0:target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:Copy /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTarget.app/PlugIns/NotifeeNotificationService.appex /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTarget-fgbhsqwnrpchqqedzhydwagitpjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NotifeeNotificationService.appex ->

node: <target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase6-bundle-react-native-code-and-images> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase6-bundle-react-native-code-and-images ->

node: <target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: <target-MyTarget-05ab8c4ac06214f0de8cc3c7e2c07d827ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase4--cp-user---rnfb--core-configuration>
```

And this is my Podfile:

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting

require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
'require.resolve(
"react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
{paths: [process.argv[1]]},
)', **dir**]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.

# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded

#

# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`

# ```js

# module.exports = {

# dependencies: {

# ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),

# ```

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.disabled
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'MyTarget' do
config = use_native_modules!

# Flags change depending on the env values.

flags = get_default_flags()

use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath], # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
:fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled], # Enables Flipper. # # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and # you should disable the next line.
:flipper_configuration => flipper_config, # An absolute path to your application root.
:app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
)
target 'MyTargetTests' do
inherit! :complete # Pods for testing
end
post_install do |installer| # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
react_native_post_install(
installer,
config[:reactNativePath],
:mac_catalyst_enabled => false
)
\_\_apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
end
end
end
end

$NotifeeExtension = true
target 'NotifeeNotificationService' do
pod 'RNNotifeeCore', :path => '../node_modules/@notifee/react-native/RNNotifeeCore.podspec'
end
````